# Компиляция Kivy под windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

Банальный вопрос по сути

Казалось бы, kivy так разрекламирован. И я опробовал - дествительно хорош.

Но на равне с плюшками встаёт доисторическая проблема - компиляция python кода.

И PyInstaller мне не помог, чего и стоило ожидать, т.к. об этом пишут почти везде. Файл запускается несколько секунд, а затем вылетает.

И в интернете об этом мало что пишут, куча танцов с бубном и использование версий питона ниже 3.4...
Да и почти на всех сайтах вроде qaru и т.д. рассматривается вопрос одного бедолаги, со своим специфическим кодом и иерархией директорий.

Мне же нужно хотя-бы научится компилировать один файл, хотя в дальнейшем, разумеется, понадобиться и прочие файлы, задействованные в проекте, запихивать в этот единственный exe.

Comment: Не помог... А что вы делали? Я на Mac спокойно компилирую Kivy приложение в exe для Windows! Не поверите - PyInstaller помог!

Comment: @Xyanight
Прописал `PyInstaller -F main.py`
Файл создался в папке dist, но при запуске висит консоль секунды три, затем буквально за мгновение поялвялется и сразу же исчезает окно

Не могли бы вы кинуть источник с инструкцией пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**install.spec:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-    

import sys
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

app_name = 'atomic_quests'
sys.path += ['src/']

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['/Users/macbookair/Projects/Q100Q/src/main.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/macbookair/Projects/Q100Q'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,

             hiddenimports=[
                 'webbrowser', 'kivymd'
             ],

             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None)

from os.path import join
from fnmatch import fnmatch

exclusion_patterns = (
    join('kivy_install', 'data', 'images', 'testpattern.png'),
    join('kivy_install', 'data', 'images', 'image-loading.png'),
    join('kivy_install', 'data', 'keyboards*'),
    join('kivy_install', 'data', 'settings_kivy.json'),
    join('kivy_install', 'data',
 'logo*'),
    join('kivy_install', 'data', 'fonts', 'DejaVuSans*'),
    join('kivy_install', 'modules*'),
    join('Include*'),
    join('sdl-config'),
    join('.idea*'),
)

def can_exclude(fn):
    for pat in exclusion_patterns:
        if fnmatch(fn, pat):
            return True

a.datas = [x for x in a.datas if not can_exclude(x[0])]
#a.datas += [('load-atom.png', '/Users/macbookair/Projects/Q100Q/src/data/images/load-atom.png', 'DATA')]
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not can_exclude(x[0])]
appfolder = [x for x in Tree('/Users/macbookair/Projects/Q100Q/src/', excludes=['*.py', '*.pyc']) if not can_exclude(x[0])]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name=app_name,
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
#          icon='/Users/macbookair/Projects/Q100Q/src/data/images/load-atom.png')

coll = COLLECT(exe, appfolder,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name=app_name)
```

**Build:**

```
wine /Users/macbookair/.wine/drive_c/Python3.6/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe /Users/macbookair/Projects/Q100Q/install.spec
```

С путями к файлам разберетесь сами.